# How to initialize list of custom object with no constructor [Dart/Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've been facing this issue, I have a mock class with static values for testing.
but I am unable to create a list for custom Object class which has no constructor as following.

```
class Video { 
  
  Video();  //this is default constructor

  late int id;
  late String name;
}
```

Problem:
Now I want to initialize a static list.

```
final List<Video> videos = [
  new Video({id = 1, name = ""}) //but this gives an error. 
];
```

> I don't want to change class constructor.

Is there any way to initialize list of custom class without constructor?

Comment: `var videos = [Video()..id = 1..name =  ''];`.  However, you really should fix the class constructor, especially with `late` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this would work:

```
final List<Video> videos = [
  Video()..id = 1..name = '',
  Video()..id = 2..name = 'another',
];
```

You basically assign the `late` properties after creating the `Video` instance, but before it's in the list.

However, it's likely that you don't need those properties to be late-initizalized and rather use a constructor for it

```
class Video { 
  
  Video({required this.id, required this.name}); 

  int id;
  String name;
}

final List<Video> videos = [
  Video(id: 1, name: ''),
  Video(id: 2, name: 'another'),
];
```

But that depends on your use case, of course

Comment: Thanks @dumazy,  the double dots annotation worked for me in this case.